# Promise is not defined in meteor-angular application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

After update to Meteor 1.2.1 and angular 1.2.0 i`m have error while build application: "ReferenceError: Promise is not defined". Before update i`m use ecmascript for es6, after update new package has been installed: angular-babel and i seen conflict between two packages — ecmascript and angular-babel. After removing ecmascript i have an error... How i can resolve this problem?

Promise using sample:

```
CSMS = class CSMS {
constructor() {
    return true;
}
createCheckCode(phoneNumber) {
    var codeBlocks = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'];
    var checkCode = '';
    for (var i = 0; i<=5; i++) checkCode += Random.choice(codeBlocks);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        HTTP.call("GET", Meteor.settings.private.smsAPIPath,
        {
            params: {
                login: Meteor.settings.private.smsAPILogin,
                psw: CryptoJS.MD5(Meteor.settings.private.smsAPIPass).toString(),
                phones: phoneNumber,
                mes: '"Близкие люди". Код подтверждения: ' + checkCode,
                charset: 'utf-8',
                fmt: 3,
                cost: 2
            }
        }, function(err, res) {
            if (err) reject(err);
            else {
                if (res.statusCode == 200) {
                    resolve({"sms":res.content, "code":checkCode});                 
                } else reject(res);
            }
        });

    });
}
```

}

And class using sample:

```
    var sms = new CSMS();
sms.createCheckCode('+79384225547').then(
    function(res) {
        console.log("SMS Sended: ", res);
    },
    function(err) {
        console.log("SMS Error:", err);
    });
```

Comment: In what environment are you running this? Are you including a polyfill?

Comment: Yes, i`m using `pbastowski:angular-babel`, this is ecmascript with ng-annotate for angular...

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved.

```
meteor add promise
```